# Change pathauto generated URL of node

Tags: views, hooks, path-aliases, uri

Does anybody know where/how to change the pathauto-URL of a node (that comes out of the db table "url_alias")?

Background (Example):

I have a page with list of nodes (A, B, C)

A -> links to "clean-URL/A.html"
B -> links to "clean-URL/B.html"
C -> should not link to "clean-URL/C.html" but to "clean-URL/A.html" (C has a field that says it should link to A)

So, I want that everywhere there is a link to C, the link should be changed to A. For example in search results or in views.

Unfortunately I can't find a pathauto hook that does something like "render_pathauto_link_of_node"...

Answer (score 1):

I found what I needed. It is the function [hook_url_outbound_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_url_outbound_alter/7)...

```
function myModule_crawler_url_outbound_alter(&$path, &$options = FALSE, $original_path){
    $mother_nid = $options['entity']->field_mother_series_nid["und"][0]["value"];
        if( $mother_nid > 0 ){
            $path = "CLEAN-URL/".$mother_nid;
            $options['alias'] = "CLEAN-URL/".$mother_nid;
        }
}
```

Thanks for helping!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure exactly you are trying to ask here, but if you use drupal's [l()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) function, it will return a link utilizing the aliases, eg:

```
$foo=l('Click here to goto bar','node/' . $nid);
```

will create a link using the url alias of the node in question (assuming of course that `$nid` contains an actual node id).

You could use this in custom PHP code or in a PHP field in Views, but, I am also thinking you could use Views' field rewriting along with tokens to accomplish this as well if it is based upon a reference field inside another node as well that is included (and then hidden) in the View's fields.

ADDITION based upon commentary:

You could take a dull ax to this and do something along these lines in hook_init()...

```
function YOURMODULE_init() {

  $mgo=menu_get_object();

  if (!empty($mgo-> /* whatever field you are talking about in your content */ )) {

    $nid= /* get the node id from that field */ ;
    if ($nid && $nid!=$mgo->nid) { 
      drupal_goto('node/' . $nid);
    }

  }

  // any other init stuff from your module goes here

}
```

...which would do the redirect upon page load so your users might see their browser address bar change quickly at the beginning but would end up at the right place.

*Also realize you'd never be able to edit the node again without further logic added into the above :)*

Comment: The l() function could be a solution. But, then I have to use it everywhere a link is rendered (e.g. in Views or in search results). Better would be a more centralized solution where the url (the way i want it) is coming automatically from the backend.

Comment: the l() function is pretty much the backend in that it is Drupal's core way of generating links. look into the built in `url()` function as well.

Comment: But, if you are asking to have pathauto automatically create an alias for one node that points to the alias of another, that's just not how it works (it adds `-#` to the end until it finds a unique one)